# Scrape Text After Specific Text and Before Specific Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                        'sku': 'T3246B5',
                        'Name': 'TAS BLACKY',
                        'Price': '111930',
                        'categories': 'Tas,Wanita,Sling Bags,Di bawah Rp 200.000',
                        'brand': '',
                        'visibility': '4',
                        'instock': "1",
                        'stock': "73.0000"

            </script>
```

I want to scrape the text between : 'stock': " and .0000" so the desireable result is 73

What I used to know is to do something like this:

```
for url2 in urls2:
        req2 = Request(url2, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/39.0.2171.95'})
        html2 = uReq(req2).read()
        page_soup2 = soup(html2, "html.parser")


        # Grab text
        stock = page_soup2.findAll("p", {"class": "stock"})
        stocks = stock[0].text
```

I used something like this in my previous code, It works before the web change their code.

But now there is more than 1 ("script", {"type": "text/javascript"}) in the entire page I want to scrape. So I dont know how to find the right ("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})

I also don't know hot to get the specific text before and after the text.

I have googled it all this day but can't find the solution. Please help.

I found that strings = 'stock': " and .0000" is unique in the entire page, only 1 'stock': and only 1 .0000"

So I think it could be the sign of location where I want to scrape the text.

Please help, thank you for your kindness.

I also apologize for my lack of English, and I am actually unfamiliar with programming. I'm just trying to learn from Google, but I can't find the answer. Thank you for your understanding.

the url = view-source:sophieparis.com/blacky-bag.html

Comment: share the url if you can

Comment: view-source:https://www.sophieparis.com/blacky-bag.html   << this is the url that I scrape. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sure `'stock'` only shows up in the script tag you want, you can pull out that text that contains `'stock`. Once you have that, it's a matter of trimming off the excess, and change to double quotes to get it into a valid json format and then simply read that in using `json.loads()`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


url2 = 'https://www.sophieparis.com/blacky-bag.html'

req2 = requests.get(url2, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/39.0.2171.95'})

page_soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req2.text, "html.parser")


scripts = page_soup2.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
    if 'stock' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('productObject = ')[-1].strip()
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('}',1)[0].strip() + '}'

        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr.replace("'",'"'))

print (jsonData['stock'].split('.')[0])
```

**Output:**

```
print (jsonData['stock'].split('.')[0])

71
```

You could also do this without the loop and just grab the script that has the string `stock` in it using 1 line:

```
jsonStr = page_soup2.find('script', text=re.compile(r'stock')).text
```

Full code would look something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re


url2 = 'https://www.sophieparis.com/blacky-bag.html'

req2 = requests.get(url2, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/39.0.2171.95'})

page_soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req2.text, "html.parser")

jsonStr = page_soup2.find('script', text=re.compile(r'stock')).text
jsonStr = jsonStr.split('productObject = ')[-1].strip()
jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('}',1)[0].strip() + '}'

jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr.replace("'",'"'))

print (jsonData['stock'].split('.')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have tried both codes and it works! Thank you very much! It's really help me! Thank you for your kindness. I have one more question, I have tried to change 'stock' into 'categories', 'brand', 'visibility', 'instock', and the code still works well. But when I change it to 'sku', 'Name', and 'Price', it won't work anymore. Is it because those 'sku', 'Name', and 'Price' are also found in another script? (it's not unique). If I also want to scrape the 'sku', 'Name', and 'Price', what should the code be?

Comment: I have tried it again and just change = print (jsonData['stock'].split('.')[0]) to print (jsonData['sku'].split('.')[0]) and it works well! thank you very much for your help ^o^

Answer (score 1):

I would write a regex that targets the javascript dictionary variable that houses the values of interest. You can apply this direct to `response.text` with no need for `bs4`.

[image]

The dictionary variable is called `productObject`, and you want the non-empty dictionary which is the second occurrence of `productObject = {..}` i.e. not the one which has 'var ' preceeding it. You can use [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to specify this requirement.

Use `hjson` to handle property names enclosed in single quotes.

---

**Py**

```
import requests, re, hjson

r = requests.get('https://www.sophieparis.com/blacky-bag.html')
p = re.compile(r'(?<!var\s)productObject = ([\s\S]*?})')
data = hjson.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
print(data)
```

---

[image]

---

**Regex:** <sub>[try](https://regex101.com/r/P3yr0m/1/)</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide me with the webpage you wish to scrape the data from, I'll see if I can fix the code to pull the information.

Comment: view-source:sophieparis.com/blacky-bag.html  << this is the url that I scrape. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Checkout Chitown88's answer, I just checked the webpage and it is the only script tag containing "stock", therefore that code will work for you.

Comment: I have checkout Chitown88's answer, and it's work well! Thank you very much for your help too. I have one more question, I have tried to change 'stock' into 'categories', 'brand', 'visibility', 'instock', and the code still works well. But when I change it to 'sku', 'Name', and 'Price', it won't work anymore. Is it because those 'sku', 'Name', and 'Price' are also found in another script? (it's not unique). If I also want to scrape the 'sku', 'Name', and 'Price', what should the code be?

Comment: I have tried it again and just change = print (jsonData['stock'].split('.')[0]) to print (jsonData['sku'].split('.')[0]) and it works well! thank you very much for your help ^o^

Comment: @Mina Mino, be sure to accept the solution if it worked for you

Comment: @chitown have accepted your answer, thank you very much!!